# cannot install xna monogame because font.spritefont.deploy is missing

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

The problem is to add the font i have to add my double clicking on .mgcb and

`edit > add > new item`

and then choose a name for my font then right click on project name from solution explorer and add > exiting item then choose my new created font .

It works fine with running my game but I got error after publish the game I cannot install it , all because this file font.spritefont.deploy it seems not exist .

Look I tried many things like changing the building action to none, compile then content all didn't work and even "Copy to output " I made it Copy always also didn't work .

I fixed the same problem by adding it by right click on projectname on solution explorer not from .mgcb file.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself , just copy all the .xnb file from bin>debug>content folder
inside the application folder and add ".deploy" to each file name then copy the .deploy files to content folder inside installation folder it worked for me with no single error .